# SFINAE used recursively

Tags: templates, c++11, sfinae

Consider this code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
    void foo() const {std::cout << "A::foo()\n";}
};

struct B {
    A value;
    void foo() const {std::cout << "B::foo()\n";}
};

struct C {
    B value;
    void foo() const {std::cout << "C::foo()\n";}
};

struct D {
    C value;
};

struct Stop {
    Stop(...) {}
};

template <typename T>
void fooValue (const T& t, Stop) {
    t.foo();
}

template <typename T, typename = decltype(T::value)>
void fooValue (const T& t, int) {
    fooValue(t.value, 0);
}

template <typename T>
void foo (const T& t) {
    fooValue(t, 0);
}

int main() {
    const D d;
    foo(d);  // A::foo()
}
```

So `A::foo()` is outputted because `A` is the last type in the chain that has a `value` member.  I want to now define

```
template <std::size_t N, typename T> void foo (const T&)
```

so that N = 0 will do the same thing, but N = 1 will have the second last type in the chain call its `foo()` function, N = 2 will have the third last type in the chain call its `foo()` function, etc...  Thus in the example above,
`foo<1>(d);` will output `B::foo()` and `foo<2>(d);` will output `C::foo()`.  But I can't think of how to implement this.  Can anyone help here?

Update:  Thanks to Ryan Haining's discussion, I've come up with the following to compute the depth during compile time:

```
template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename = void>
struct ChainLength : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ChainLength<T, N, void_t<decltype(T::value)>> : ChainLength<decltype(T::value), N+1> {};
```

Now we only need to use it properly.

Comment: doing this with just functions would require partial template specialization (which you can't do) so you'll need a helper `struct`

Comment: Are you sure your `<1>`and `<2>` example cases aren't backwards?

Comment: `N` here is supposed to correspond to the Nth last successful substitution.  At any rate, I'll take any syntax that will get the job done.

Comment: How does N=2 go one step from `D` to `C` while N=1 goes two steps from `D` to `C` to `B`? Would N=0 mean `A`?

Comment: Well, I said `Nth last`, not `Nth`.  Yes N=0 will output `A::foo()`.  We can use your syntax, but then how do we get the last (or second last, ect...) type call its `foo()` function if we don't know how long the chain is?  ... Oh that gives me an idea:  calculate how long the chain is in advance first, then my N value can be used to get your N value (and then your partial specialization idea can be used).

Comment: Ok I see what you mean now, yes you'd have to calculate the depth first and then count backwards from the bottom

Answer (score 1):

This is thanks to the discussion with Ryan Haining:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
using void_t = void;

template <typename T, std::size_t N, typename = void>
struct ChainLength : std::integral_constant<std::size_t, N> {};

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
struct ChainLength<T, N,
    void_t<decltype(std::declval<decltype(T::value)>().foo())>> :
    ChainLength<decltype(T::value), N+1> {};  // Here we check not only that T::data exists, but that decltype(T::data) has a foo() member function too.

template <std::size_t Count, typename T>
struct FooData {
    static void execute (const T& t) {
        FooData<Count-1, decltype(T::value)>::execute(t.value);
    }
};

template <typename T>
struct FooData<0, T> {
    static void execute (const T& t) { t.foo(); }
};

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Length, typename T>
void fooHelper (const T& t, std::enable_if_t<(N < Length)>* = nullptr) {
    FooData<Length-N, T>::execute(t);
}

template <std::size_t N, std::size_t Length, typename T>
void fooHelper (const T&, std::enable_if_t<(N >= Length)>* = nullptr) {
    std::cout << "N value too big.\n";
}

template <std::size_t N, typename T>
void foo (const T& t) {
    fooHelper<N, ChainLength<T,0>::value>(t);
}

// Testing
struct A {
    void foo() const {std::cout << "A::foo()\n";}
};

struct B {
    A value;
    void foo() const {std::cout << "B::foo()\n";}
};

struct C {
    B value;
    void foo() const {std::cout << "C::foo()\n";}
};

struct D {
    C value;
};

int main() {
    const D d;
    foo<0>(d);  // A::foo()  (this is outputted because A is the last type in the chain that has a 'value' member)
    foo<1>(d);  // B::foo()  (this is outputted because B is the second last type in the chain that has a 'value' member)
    foo<2>(d);  // C::foo()  (this is outputted because C is the third last type in the chain that has a 'value' member)
    foo<3>(d);  // N value too big.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The plan is to do everything with functions instead of with types.

First, a wrapper for integral constant to reduce typing:

```
template<std::size_t I>
using index_t = std::integral_constant<std::size_t, I>;
template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I> index = {};
```

Now, some simple operations on it:

```
template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
constexpr index_t<A+B> add(index_t<A>, index_t<B>){ return {}; }

template<std::size_t A, std::size_t B>
constexpr index_t<A-B> sub(index_t<A>, index_t<B>){ return {}; }

template<std::size_t I>
constexpr index_t<I+1> next( index_t<I> ) { return {}; };
```

Calculate depth as an index:

```
template<class T>
constexpr index_t<0> fooIndex(const T& t, Stop) {
  return {};
}

template<class T, class = decltype(T::value)>
constexpr auto fooIndex(const T& t, int) {
  return next(fooIndex(t.value, 0));
}
```

Invoke at a specific depth:

```
template<class T>
void fooValue(const T& t, index_t<0>) {
  t.foo();
}
template<class T, std::size_t I>
void fooValue(const T& t, index_t<I>) {
  fooValue(t.value, index<I-1>);
}
```

Use them:

```
template <typename T>
void foo (const T& t) {
  auto idx = fooIndex(t, 0);
  return fooValue( t, sub( idx, index<1> ) ); 
}
```

Comment: Wow.  I'll try to make your ideas compile, but I didn't think that my original method could still be used and modified to work.  I thought Ryan Haining's idea of revising with partial template specializations with helper structs was the only way.

Comment: @prestokeys The `index` template variable is C++14; you can replace its use of `index<N>` with `index_t<N>{}`